# Custom Fonts for DOMPDF

Tags: php, pdf-generation, dompdf, custom-font

I'm Using DOM PDF 0.6.0 Beta 2. I want to use custom fonts (Fonts: 'Segeo Print', 'Lucida Handwriting','Airplanes in the Night Sky') in PDF file.

I followed the guidelines to install and use fonts in my PHP Code, which is given here http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/CPDFUnicode

But I'm not able to get desire fonts in my PDF. You can find my code in this post. Please Let me know how I can resolve this issue.

```
<?php     
    require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");

   $html = "<html>
                <head>   
                    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8'>
                    <style>
                        *{font-size:15px;}  
                        div.ClJ{font: nightsky;}   
                    </style>      
                </head>
                <body>            
                   <div class='ClJ'>This text is in DIV Element</div><br /><br />
                </body>
          </html>";

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();    
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $pdf = $dompdf->output();
    $dompdf->stream("dompdf_out.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));

?>
```

Comment: If you're still on beta 2, try upgrading to beta 3. It has better support for custom fonts, now supports font-subetting, and has an easier font-loading mechanism (the how-to needs to be updated to reflect these changes).

Comment: FYI, your code looks fine so it's probably an issue with the font itself (e.g. font didn't load correctly).

Comment: Thank your the comment. Will try to upgrade to beta 3 lets see how its turn out.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. go to your DOMPDF folder
2. copy your font's as .ttf (TrueType Font) or .otf (OpenType Font) into the DOMPDF's root
3. open your command line and run

   ```
   php load_font.php your_fonts_name ./your-normal.ttf ./your-bold.ttf ./your-bold-italic.ttf
   ```
4. DOMPDF now created Adobe Font Metrics and copied it to lib/fonts/* - you can now use it with

   ```
   font-family: your_fonts_name;
   ```

Comment: @ueli : I dont did not instal but just copy pasted dompdf. how shall i do?

Comment: I think there's a comma after the second filename that may cause error, the code should be:
php load_font.php your_fonts_name ./your-normal.ttf ./your-bold.ttf ./your-bold-italic.ttf

Comment: This does not work for me. Pulled in fresh version from github (https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/). When running the command, I get: `Warning: require_once(/Users/me/Downloads/dompdf-master/lib/php-font-lib/classes/Font.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/me/Downloads/dompdf-master/dompdf_config.inc.php on line 332`

Comment: @Kannu why is it inappropriate?

Comment: @Mattias and anybody else who pulls DOMPDF from github. You must initialise and update the submodules. This is why you got file not found error
    "git submodule init && git submodule update"

Comment: answer doesn't work for composer based insallatation of DomPDF. Also, this is not correct way to change core directory

Answer (score 12):

you can add css font :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: new_font;
    src: url('my_font.ttf');
}
```

and than

```
div.ClJ{
    font-family: new_font; 
}
```

Comment: I don't think so this is accessory as I have already installed fonts for DOM PDF and definition of fonts are already available in dompdf_font_family_cache.dist file

Comment: where should i keep this css part ?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to **install custom fonts to the server without a command-based** interface
then you can do the following web-based model to install the custom fonts

1. Download ejaz.php from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q1ifg519gr138ev/ejaz.php?dl=0)
2. Put this file to the root of dompdf and follow the instruction written in it

no need for root or command/terminal access