# Running 'php load_font.php' fails: "No such file or directory"

Tags: php, dompdf

I am trying to run:

php load_font.php montserrat ./Montserrat-Bold.otf

(as per described here: [Custom Fonts for DOMPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581156/custom-fonts-for-dompdf))

But it results in the following error:

```
Warning: require_once(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/wp-content/themes/project/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/php-font-lib/classes/Font.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/wp-content/themes/project/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php on line 332

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/wp-content/themes/project/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/php-font-lib/classes/Font.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.14/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/wp-content/themes/project/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php on line 332
```

Why??

Comment: Why?? Because the file doesn't exist where you say it does. The error is very self-explanatory. ;-)

Comment: How did you get dompdf? The source code [does not include php-font-lib](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dompdf+font+class), and if you're using Composer you should set `DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD` to false in the config file (dompdf_config.inc.php).